# Highlight the selected cell in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview, cell, right-click

In my code below, I'm showing a context menu when the user right-clicks on a cell in my DataGridView.  I'd also like the cell that the user right-clicks on to change background color so that they can see the cell they've "right-click selected".  Is there a way to add something to my code below so that this occurs?

```
private void dataGridView2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem mnuCopy = new MenuItem("Copy");
            mnuCopy.Click += new EventHandler(mnuCopy_Click);
            m.MenuItems.Add(mnuCopy);

            int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView2.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;               

            m.Show(dataGridView2, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So obviously you've hacked into my workstation and have seen some of the stuff I've worked on recently.  I exaggerate a bit because I didn't do exactly what you're trying to do but with a little bit of tweaking I was able to.

I would modify your `MouseClick` event to get the DGV's `CurrentCell`.  Once you have it, set the `CurrentCell`'s `Style` property with the `SelectionBackColor` you want.  Something like this:

```
// ...
DataGridView.HitTestInfo hti = dataGridView2.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
if (hti.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell) {
    dataGridView2.CurrentCell = dataGridView2.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Cells[hti.ColumnIndex];
    dataGridView2.CurrentCell.Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow};
}
//...
```

The above is a bit 'air code-y' (in other words I haven't attempted to merge it with your code and run it) but I hope you get the idea.  Notice that I check through the hit test that a cell was clicked; if you don't do this and the user does not click a cell you might have some problems.

Now there's the problem that this code will change the `SelectionBackColor` for the all the cells you right click.  That's easy to restore this property in the DGV's `CellLeave` event:

```
private void dgvBatches_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    dataGridView2.CurrentCell.Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight };
}
```

I'll have to remember this visual affect; thanks for asking the question.

Comment: Sorry about hacking into your workstation!  Oh, and ignore those hidden cameras in your office, too.  Also, if you get a call from some guy named Gary Winston from NURV software, hang up.  Thanks!!